# cURL - max-time option doesn't affect. Process is not stopped

Tags: curl

**I have the command like:**

```
curl --connect-timeout 6 --max-time 60 -v -L --max-redirs 10 -k "https://s3.somehost.com/ju..."
```

In most cases it works fine. But sometimes it hangs. Just no any output and a process is not stopped.
There is the option `--max-time` (same as -m). It is set for 60 seconds, but after 60 seconds the process still hangs.

What can be the reason?
Can it be a curl bug?

I don't have the latest version. It is curl 7.29.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was not in curl.

I executed it now from terminal, but from other program using pipes. 
Ad curl sends debug info to stderr (headers, etc). I my other program stderr buffer was too small, curl was not able to write all data and waited when buffer is freed . But the program didn't free it. This was my bug.

So, no problems with curl at all